# How to write a tree with no (visible) root with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I’m trying to write a tree structure in TikZ. The trees in question are labelled on the leaf only; there is no label on inner nodes. Because I don’t use `node` on inner nodes, the tree structure joins. However, it seems I still need to write a `\node` to start the tree. While I can leave its label empty, it is still displayed as a white circle which disconnect the structure. How can I avoid this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% The broken structure bothers me
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {}
    child { node {a} }
    child {
      child {node {b}}
      child {node {c}}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

% This is what I want, but without the added root.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {} % this node should not exist
  child {
    child { node {a} }
    child {
      child {node {b}}
      child {node {c}}
    }
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this is what you want:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate
  child { node {a} }
  child {
    child {node {b}}
    child {node {c}}
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]