# Trees with only leaves in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, forest

Following Roel's answer to [How to write a tree with no (visible) root with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133304/how-to-write-a-tree-with-no-visible-root-with-tikz) I attempted to visualise my Huffman-Code for "Tennessee", but it didn't turn out as I expected:[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm, level distance = 1.5cm}] 
    \coordinate
            child {node [circle,draw] {E} edge from parent node[left] {\textcolor{red}{0}}} 
        child {edge from parent node[right]{\textcolor{red}{1}} 
            child {node [circle,draw] {S} edge from parent node[left] {\textcolor{red}{0}}}
            child {edge from parent node[right]{\textcolor{red}{1}}
                    child {node [circle,draw]{N} edge from parent node[left] {\textcolor{red}{0}}}
                    child {node [circle,draw]{T} edge from parent node[right] {\textcolor{red}{1}}}
                }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously the numbering on the edges is not being level and more importantly, the edges are overlapping.

I experimented with removing the style, but that just leaves the tree narrower yet does *not* resolve the issue of the missing edge alignment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please describe a little more detailed what you want to achieve? Or draw a little sketch. Maybe its my poor English, but I do not really get the question. Thanks.

Comment: Basically I would like the tree to be a smooth tree with the edges as a continous unbroken line (preferably) following the same angle, just as if inner nodes where indeed present. I would like it to look as the answer by Roel in the linked question does, except with edge labels and circled leaf nodes.

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of [How do I make trees with straight skeletons or spines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168807/42880), although I think this question is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to put the `edge from parent` operation at the end of the corresponding `child` path declaration, like in the following :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm, level distance = 1.5cm}, leaf/.style={circle, draw}, label/.style={red},edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode)}] 
    \coordinate[child anchor=south]
        child {node[leaf] {E} edge from parent node[left, label] {0}} 
        child {
            child {node [leaf] {S} edge from parent node[left, label] {0}}
            child {
                child {node [leaf]{N} edge from parent node[left, label] {0}}
                child {node [leaf]{T} edge from parent node[right, label] {1}}
                edge from parent node[right, label]{1}
            }
            edge from parent node[right, label]{1}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I added styles to get a cleaner code, and redefined `edge from parent path` to align the nodes (redefining `child anchor` and `parent anchor` should be enough, but there seems to be a bug with it in my version of Tikz)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution using [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) package. The code for `nice empty nodes` is adapted from example 81 in `forest` documentation.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\forestset{
    nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate, for parent={for children={anchor=north}}}{circle, draw}}
},
    zero/.style={edge label={node[midway, left] {0}}},
    one/.style={edge label={node[midway, right] {1}}},
}

    \begin{forest}
    [ , nice empty nodes,  
        [E, zero] 
        [, one
            [S, zero] 
            [,one
                [N, zero]
                [T, one]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Gonzalo's version**

Next code was provided by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina). It automates edge labels.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{forest} 
    for tree={%   
        calign=fixed edge angles,   
        delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},   
        parent anchor=south,   
        where n children=0{circle,draw}{},   
        s sep=1.5cm,   
        if n=1 { 
            edge label={%     
                node[midway,auto,swap,font=\color{red}\scriptsize]{0}}     
        }{%
            if n'=1 {
                edge label={%      
                    node[midway,auto,font=\color{red}\scriptsize]{1}}      
            }{}    
        } 
    }  
    [ [E] [ [S] [ [N] [T] ] ] ] 
\end{forest}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I was writing something similar, so no point in duplicating answers. You can simplify a little your code, since the labels can be automated:

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  calign=fixed edge angles,
  delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
  parent anchor=south,
  where n children=0{circle,draw}{},
  s sep=1.5cm,
  if n=1{edge label={
    node[midway,auto,swap,font=\color{red}\scriptsize]{0}}
    }
   {if n'=1{edge label={
     node[midway,auto,font=\color{red}\scriptsize]{1}}
     }{}
   }
} 
[
  [E]
  [
    [S]
    [
      [N]
      [T]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry about the poor code formatting, but comments are a PITA for code :(

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I've included your code. Please feel free to edit. And thanks for your comment. I'm just starting to understand and use forest `programming` power so your examples are always helpful.

Comment: Brilliant solution. I accepted Tonio's answer mainly because it corrects my original coding - basically it answers the question what was wrong with it. However, if there is the possibility the tree is going to be expanded at some point (or there is more than one in the document), your solution is probably the way to go, especially after moving most of it in the preamble and then being able to easily plant trees everywhere with very little code per tree. I certainly am going to take a look into forest.